# How to add cryptopp to project in OMNeT++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, omnet++, crypto++

First, I built the cryptlib (of cryptopp) in Visual Studio Code 2022. And tried a sample c++ program (using files from the library) and it worked fine. 
Then, I included the library `cryptlib.lib` in my OMNeT++ project. 
I also included the cryptopp folder for the .cpp and .h files of the library. 
But when I build the omnet++ project, I get this error:

> 03:05:22 **** Incremental Build of configuration debug for project crypto_final ****
> make MODE=debug all
> cd src && /usr/bin/make
> make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDRgk.png): Entering directory '/d/omnetpp-5.7/samples/crypto_final/src'
> Server.cc
> Creating executable: ../out/clang-debug/src/crypto_final_dbg.exe
> lld-link: error: could not open 'liblibcpmt.a': No such file or directory
> lld-link: error: could not open 'libLIBCMT.a': No such file or directory
> lld-link: error: could not open 'libOLDNAMES.a': No such file or directory
> clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> make[1]: *** [Makefile:99: ../out/clang-debug/src/crypto_final_dbg.exe] Error 1
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/d/omnetpp-5.7/samples/crypto_final/src'
> make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 2
> "make MODE=debug all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
> 03:05:25 Build Failed. 2 errors, 0 warnings. (took 3s.352ms)

I don't even know what are these libraries or how to get them built.
Can anyone help, please?

Edit #1: btw, when I change the Target type from "Executable" to "Static library (.lib or .a) in makemake options, the project builds normally but does not run properly (has some bugs and no effects can appear on the simulation)

Comment: Hi. I hope you have followed the steps to include external libraries in OMNET++. If not check here https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=R37YtvAIIYg

Comment: @Mohammed Hani: Changing target is not necessary. You want to **add** a static library to your project, not to create a static library.

Answer (score 0):

OMNeT++ project uses Makefile, therefore to add an external library or class one should modify makefrag.
You should go to `Project` | `Properties` | `OMNeT++` | `Makemake` | select root or src of your project | `Options`, then `Custom` | `Makefrag` and write the following lines:

```
EXTRA_OBJS += -L/d/foo/lib -llibcpmt -lLIBCMT -lOLDNAMES
CFLAGS += -I/d/foo/include
```

where `/d/foo/lib` is an example of the directory which contains your `cryptlib` static files (e.g. `liblibcpmt.a`, `libLIBCMT.a`, ... ), and `/d/foo/include` - the directory that contains header files of `cryptlib`.

Comment: I did that but the compiler cannot find these static files of cryptlib in the cryptlib folder

Answer (score 0):

Omnet++ useses MinGW as the runtime system and the C++ compiler's ABI is incompatible with the MS ABI (i.e. C++ code generated by Visual Studio C++ compiler is **incompatible** with the code generted by `gcc` or `clang`).

You MUST compile your crypto library also with the `clang` compiler coming with OMNeT++. Visual Studio compiler will NOT work.

Or... OpenSSL libraries and headers are already available in the Windows distro, so you can pt to use that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you tell me how to compile the library using clang compiler (or using omnet++)